# ODBC driver on windows cannot be loaded

Tags: python, odbc, teradata

I am trying to make a connection to Teradata in python using DSN:

```
def setup_tconnection():
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec( appName="test", version = "1.0", configureLogging="False")    
session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", DSN= "Teradata64")
```

but when i run the connection code:

```
tconn = setup_tconnection()
```

it gives me following error:

```
[IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  193:  (Teradata, C:\Program Files\Teradata\Client\14.10\ODBC Driver for Teradata nt-x8664\Lib\tdata32.dll).
```

I have both ODBC 32 bit and 64 bit... The python version is 64 so I added DSN to ODBC 64 but it's not working. any idea what's wrong here?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried every suggestion that people mentioned online, non of them worked, I checked the Teradata package and I found out even though I changed my path to point to Teradata 15 (newer version) it is still working with Teradata 14...so I un-installed the old version of teradata and re-installed the new version and it is working...